# Como me conectar ao SOpt se tenho uma conta?

Tags: debate

Não fui capaz de encontrar essa opção. Se clico em "Faça uma pergunta" ele me dá um link para Login, mas na tela posterior somente tenho a opção de criar nova conta.

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1110/55024

Comment: Coloca o screen shot de como aparece para você o login.

Answer (score 6):

O link direto para o login é: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/login

Porém, se estivermos falando da mesma tela, existem algumas opções para fazer isso na própria tela, como mostro na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]